# java generic method, runtime error,

Tags: java

When I tried to run the code below, the compiler generates

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: JTOGenerics.ArrayCode.countGreaterThan
    at JTOGenerics.ArrayCode.main(ArrayCode.java:17)
Java Result: 1

There is a red line beneath the line of code:
    int av = ArrayCode.countGreaterThan(marks, 10);

I'm new to Java and due to my limited knowledge, I tried and failed to locate the error, could someone please help me out? Many thanks in advance!!

```
public class ArrayCode<T> implements Comparable<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] marks = new Integer[] {12, 0, 15, 18, 4};
        int av = ArrayCode.countGreaterThan(marks, 10);
        System.out.println("the number of Marks that are greater than 10 is: " + av);

    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
        int count = 0;
        for (T e : anArray) {
            if (((Comparable<T>)e).compareTo(elem) > 0) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        if (this.equals(o)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public interface Comparable<T> {

        public int compareTo(T o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined your own `Comparable` interface within the `ArrayCode` class.  It appears that the type bound for the generic `static` method `countGreaterThan` is resolving to that `Comparable` interface.  However, `Integer` implements the built-in `java.lang.Comparable` interface instead.

Remove your own `Comparable` interface, which means `Comparable` will refer to the built-in `Comparable` interface.

In addition, the `ArrayCode` class doesn't need to implement `Comparable` itself (unless there is other non-static code that we aren't seeing in your post); you can remove `implements Comparable<T>` on `ArrayCode`, `ArrayCode`'s own `T` type parameter, and `ArrayCode`'s `compareTo` method also.  Plus, you don't need the cast to `Comparable<T>` in the `if` condition; it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you've created your own interface called `Comparable`.

`Integer` does not implement your version.

I would just get rid of your version.